# Как написать функцию отображения числа на дисплее для микроконтроллеров с учётом стирания символов при обновлении числа в меньшую сторону

Tags: c, arduino, stm32, микроконтроллеры

Когда отображаем на дисплее (не важно на каком, OLED, LCD, TFT) число, скажем, "100", а потом оно обновилось, скажем, на "99", то как правильно стереть лишний символ? На чистом Си без использования классов.
Понимаю, что вопрос глупый, но ответ в гуглах я не нашёл и не додумался сам, т.к., I'm new in programming)
Что я пробовал? Создавал структуру и для вывода каждого значения (если выводится несколько значений на мониторе в разных местах) использовал различные объекты структуры. В глобальной структуре записывается строка. Если strlen следующего числа-строки меньше, то рисуем предыдущее число цветом фона, затирая его, и пишем новое. В структуру записываем новое число.
Есть ли другие, более умные и оптимизированные варианты решения этой проблемы?
Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: А почему бы просто не добавлять нужное количество пробелов с нужной стороны, чтобы новое значение было не короче старого? их вывод затрёт "лишние символы". А следующий вывод - уже с учётом длины того, которое при предыдущем выводе было "новым". Или ты не знаешь что там было? тогда просто добавляй на всю длину вывода.

Comment: `\b` потом вывести пробел.

Comment: *"не важно на каком"* - нет, это принципиально важно, и следовало бы привести [mcve] того, с чем вы работает

Answer (score -1):

Решение вашей задачи зависит от контекста.
Для отображения одной строки, самый очевидный способ формировать
строку с максимальной длинной и переписывать её целиком.
Пусть размер экрана вмещает 5 символов. Тогда:

```
char str[5+1]; // еще одни символ для конца строки
sprintf(str, "%5d",123);
std::cout<<str; // выводите строку на экран
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Тогда разные переменные в разных участках дисплея будут представлять собой отображение строки с константной длиной, которая будет одинаковая для всех выводимых переменных. Тем самым, мы сможем обойтись без экземпляров структур. Но мы не сможем динамически менять длину строки (даже для малых значений чисел будет "тратиться" участок дисплея на max_string_length). Верно?

Comment: Верно. Однако, если у Вас достаточно памяти, и отображение происходит без мерцания, то это, на мой взгляд,  приемлемый вариант.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую реализовать!